# Is my logic valid in this rates of change question?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

[image: question]

> A hemispherical bowl of radius $r$ is initially empty. Water is poured into it at a constant rate of $k$cm$^3$ per minute. When the depth of water in the bowl is $x$ c,, the volume of water in the
> bowl is given by $v\ =\ \frac{\pi}{3}x^{2}\left(3r-x\right)$. Show that it takes 3.5 times as long to fill the bowl to the point where $x = \frac{2r}{3}$ as it does to fill the bowl to the point where $x = \frac{r}{3}$

For part (ii), I simply subbed the two $x$ values into $V$ and divided them to get the ratio of $3.5$ since water is poured in at a **constant** rate. The solutions go through a lengthy process of integrating to find $t$, then finding times are $t_1$ and $t_2$ to show that $t_1 = 3.5 t_2$. Is my way valid? My thinking is that since the rate is constant, you can measure the volume at $ x = t_1 = \frac{2r}{3}$ and divide that by the volume when $x = \frac{r}{3}$ to see the *extent* to which filling up to $x_1$ is compared to $x_2$. Then can I conclude that it is logically indeed $3.5$?

Comment: Yes the logic is sound. Just make sure to explain it well for $2$ marks :)

Comment: Thanks! Luckily it says "or otherwise"

Comment: Actually, I *am* doing "hence" since I am technically using the volume formula, which is given

Comment: Yes I would avoid integrating to get the answer as the question specifically does not seek it.